# Selenium - Firefox - Issue in xpath with Div tags SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression

Tags: html, firefox, selenium, xpath, relative-path

I am getting below error while trying to automate sample Qlikview web report though **Selenium**

**Browser:** Firefox

**Xpath returned by FirePath:**

```
  .//*[@id='58']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]
```

Exception:

```
  **Exception**: Exception in thread "main"                 
   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given    
   selector//[@id='58']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1] is either invalid          
   or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:      
   InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath       
   expression //[@id='58']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1] because of the     
   following error:**SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.**
   Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds
   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org       
   /exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
    Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
```

I tried running by removing '.' from xpath but still the same error is occuring.

**Code Sample:**

// Navigate to Quarter 4 Results

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='58']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]")).click();
}
```

**Application:** http://us-b.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs%2FRetail%20Omni-Channel%20Analytics.qvw&host=demo11&anonymous=true

I am trying to click Q4 link on this application

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give tag name in your xpath. You didn't mention any tag name. You can give `*` that can take any tag.

```
 //*[@id='58']
```

The above will match any element that has id=58

You have used

```
 //[@id='58']
```

in which the tag name is missing.So it's an invalid selector.You have to mention `*` or proper tagName of the element like `div` or something

use below line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='58']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]")).click();
```

instead of:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='58']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Actually This diidnt work .. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Your error clearly specifying that your xpath expression is wrong. That is only the problem. If you tried this, your code will be clear at this line, there may some other line which has same problem.

Comment: This is the link I am referring to http://us-b.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs%2FRetail%20Omni-Channel%20Analytics.qvw&host=demo11&anonymous=true  code error has been removed but execption is thrown

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); adding wait has solved the issue